# Why doesn't the dash work on Ubuntu's Unity desktop environment when I try to search online?

Tags: 20.04, unity, unity-dash

I use the Unity desktop environment on Ubuntu 20.04. I enable online searching in Settings, but it still does not let me search the web from the dash. When I tried installing dash plugins that would allow me to search the web, Unity crashed and I had to reinstall it.

How do I overcome this?